# How to get interactive html output from JasperReports?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using *JasperReports* to generate various high end reports. But my requirement is for web based dynamic reports. The output is in *html* format and I want it to be interactive and not static. The functionalities similar to *Jquery DataTables* (like column hiding, sorting, filtering, etc ).

But for applying *Jquery DataTables* to the generated html , "thead" tag and "table-'id' " is required which is not there in *JR* html template by default.

Can I edit the html template from where *JR* generate *html*? If yes how?

Is there any alternative to *Jquery DataTables* provided by *JR Server* as I have heard of *JasperReports Server*?

Comment: You can try *JR Server*. The community version is free

Comment: @Alex K : Thanks for your suggestion. But is there any way to edit _html_ generated by _JR_ so that i can apply _Jquery Datatables_ to it.